# How to populate RRD database with CPU and MEM usage data?

Tags: linux, centos, shell, rrdtool

I have a Lighttpd server (on Centos) and would like to display 4 graphs: lighttpd traffic, lighttpd requests per second, CPU usage and MEM usage. I've set place for rrd database for lighttpd config like this:

```
rrdtool.binary = "/usr/bin/rrdtool"
rrdtool.db-name = "/var/www/lighttpd.rrd"
```

And put into my WWW cgi-bin sh file that gets data from lighttpd RRD file and creates graphs of traffic and requests per second like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

RRDTOOL=/usr/bin/rrdtool
OUTDIR=//var/www/graphs
INFILE=/var/www/lighttpd.rrd
OUTPRE=lighttpd-traffic
WIDTH=400
HEIGHT=100

DISP="-v bytes --title TrafficWebserver \
        DEF:binraw=$INFILE:InOctets:AVERAGE \
        DEF:binmaxraw=$INFILE:InOctets:MAX \
        DEF:binminraw=$INFILE:InOctets:MIN \
        DEF:bout=$INFILE:OutOctets:AVERAGE \
        DEF:boutmax=$INFILE:OutOctets:MAX \
        DEF:boutmin=$INFILE:OutOctets:MIN \
        CDEF:bin=binraw,-1,* \
        CDEF:binmax=binmaxraw,-1,* \
        CDEF:binmin=binminraw,-1,* \
        CDEF:binminmax=binmaxraw,binminraw,- \
        CDEF:boutminmax=boutmax,boutmin,- \
        AREA:binmin#ffffff: \
        STACK:binmax#f00000: \
        LINE1:binmin#a0a0a0: \
        LINE1:binmax#a0a0a0: \
        LINE2:bin#efb71d:incoming \
        GPRINT:bin:MIN:%.2lf \
        GPRINT:bin:AVERAGE:%.2lf \
        GPRINT:bin:MAX:%.2lf \
        AREA:boutmin#ffffff: \
        STACK:boutminmax#00f000: \
        LINE1:boutmin#a0a0a0: \
        LINE1:boutmax#a0a0a0: \
        LINE2:bout#a0a735:outgoing \
        GPRINT:bout:MIN:%.2lf \
        GPRINT:bout:AVERAGE:%.2lf \
        GPRINT:bout:MAX:%.2lf \
        " 

$RRDTOOL graph $OUTDIR/$OUTPRE-hour.png -a PNG --start -14400 $DISP -w $WIDTH -h $HEIGHT
$RRDTOOL graph $OUTDIR/$OUTPRE-day.png -a PNG --start -86400 $DISP -w $WIDTH -h $HEIGHT
$RRDTOOL graph $OUTDIR/$OUTPRE-month.png -a PNG --start -2592000 $DISP -w $WIDTH -h $HEIGHT

OUTPRE=lighttpd-requests

DISP="-v req --title RequestsperSecond -u 1 \
        DEF:req=$INFILE:Requests:AVERAGE \
        DEF:reqmax=$INFILE:Requests:MAX \
        DEF:reqmin=$INFILE:Requests:MIN \
        CDEF:reqminmax=reqmax,reqmin,- \
        AREA:reqmin#ffffff: \
        STACK:reqminmax#00f000: \
        LINE1:reqmin#a0a0a0: \
        LINE1:reqmax#a0a0a0: \
        LINE2:req#00a735:requests" 

$RRDTOOL graph $OUTDIR/$OUTPRE-hour.png -a PNG --start -14400 $DISP -w $WIDTH -h $HEIGHT
$RRDTOOL graph $OUTDIR/$OUTPRE-day.png -a PNG --start -86400 $DISP -w $WIDTH -h $HEIGHT
$RRDTOOL graph $OUTDIR/$OUTPRE-month.png -a PNG --start -2592000 $DISP -w $WIDTH -h $HEIGHT
```

Basically it's not my script, i get it from somewhere from the internet. 
Now i would like to do the same for CPU usage and MEM usage. 
I don't like to use any additional packages!

As you can see lighttpd populates lighttpd.rrd file with traffic data and requests per second. Now i would like to the system to populate second rrd file with CPU and MEM usage, so i can add to sh file code to generate graphs for this data.

How can I populate RRD file with CPU and MEM usage data?
Please, NO THIRD-PARTY tools !

Comment: Why no 3rd party tools? There are tons of great packages for system monitoring like Cacti, monit or MRTG out there, so why to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @SvenW Because I need to have a control over these data and be able to incorporate them into more complex log-notice system.

Answer (score 1):

So, if you want to really control that yourself, you will first need to define your own rrd file for this data, meaning you need to know what you want to store for how long. Then you have to populate this, likely from a script. The data you are looking for is in /proc/meminfo and /proc/loadavg, you have to parse this data and feed it into rrdtool.

How to define and populate your own rrd file is [documented excellently](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/tut/rrd-beginners.en.html) by the rrdtool creators, so I'll just refer you to this documentation.

Comment: It's no brainer to go to the site you mentioned and see that is far from the answer to this question.

Comment: Hmmh, I told you that there are many tools out there that do what you want, but you insist on rolling your own. Then I told you where you can learn how to use rrdtool and where to find the info you want to log, but that isn't sufficient either. So what do you expect? That someone here writes this script for you? Sorry, but I'll pass...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is worth to take a look how collectd (a small C daemon collecting statistics to rrd files) does it:

http://git.verplant.org/?p=collectd.git;a=blob;f=src/cpu.c;h=12071a2ca8bae25cf86f25782a682ad1bf898846;hb=HEAD#l363

Here you can find how it reads `/proc/stat` and parses its content then you can easily write a bash script.